# Looking for quote and source

Tags: story-identification, quotes

The book covers such a long period of time, history up to current time is covered in one sentence, something like,”It was a time of great religious and political turmoil.”

I was sure it was from “Last and First Men” by Olaf Stapledon, but after searching for key words and rereading the story I can’t find the quote.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you specify any science fiction or fantasy elements that featured in this book? We could also use more details regarding the plot. Knowing the approximate year in which you read this might help, too.

Comment: Not what you're looking for but I'm reminded of this quotation:: "Following the death of Jesus Christ, there was a period of readjustment that lasted for approximately one million years."

Comment: Sounds like it could almost be from *Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy*

Comment: Which words in the remembered quote are you 100% sure occur in the original? What was the context of the quote? Was it part of the author's narration, or was it spoken by a character in the story? Was it part of a history lecture? Was it spoked by a human, an alien, a robot?

Comment: If it was from Last and First Men it was spoken to a human from today by a human in the distant future. I have read Sirens Of Titan. I’ve read a lot of SiFi over the last 65 years. After researching for this paraphrase I’m guessing I am way off, but it is so clear in my memory.

Answer (score 11):

I wonder if you're thinking of this, from Kurt Vonnegut's **The Sirens of Titan**:

> The million-year period to which the burned junk related would be
> summed up in history books in one sentence, according to Koradubian:
> **Following the death of Jesus Christ, there was a period of
> readjustment that lasted for approximately one million years.**

Comment: That line is in the list of sci-fi quotations on my profile page!

Comment: Being new here I’m not sure how to reply. I was sue it was from Last and First Men, but doubt my memory now. I’ve read Sirens of Titan. Should I mark the question as likely answered? User14111

Comment: It's up to you. If you're not quite sure, feel free to take your time to think about it

Comment: @Nick Have you read *The Sirens of Titan*? It's probably **not** the one you're looking for, because the actual story does **not** cover a long period of time. When you sau "history up to current time" does "current time" refer to something close to **our** current time, or is it some time far in our future?

Comment: The quote covers history from the beginning of recorded history until modern times. (1930’s) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_and_First_Men